# If foreach value appear, add some data

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I got:

```
foreach ($query as $sample) {
[..]
}
```

And I need it to be changed so if all values with

`$sample['key'] == 1`

Gonna be looped by the foreach and the next loop will have `$sample['key'] == 0` , then it'll add for example something like:

```
<tr><td colspan="4">All keys with $sample['key'] == 1 are after the loop, and I'm staring to loop with $sample['key'] == 0</td></tr>
```

But only once.

//edited

Trying to explain more:

At first: `foreach` will loop this:

```
foreach($query as $sample) {
*loop*
print_r($sample['key']) //1
*loop*
print_r($sample['key']) //1
...etc.
}
```

But if there'll be something like:

```
foreach($query as $sample) {
*loop*
print_r($sample['key']) //1
*loop*
*adding some content, because next print value is 0!*
print_r($sample['key']) //0!!!!!!!
}
```

Hope you understand it now, I've done my best to explain as best as I can. It's  hard to describe, so if you have some questions, feel free to ask in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want. Is this it: "The first time an array element is `1` and the very next element is `0`, you want to generate an ouput."?

Comment: edited my question, hope you'll understand it now :)

Comment: i am not sure what you are saying.do you need to get output like this?
the first element value should be 1 and other elements value 0.
am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand the question, but it sounds almost like [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) may be of some help:

```
function KeyIsEqualToOne($ary){
  return $ary['key'] == 1;
}

function KeyIsEqualToZero($ary){
  return $ary['key'] == 0;
}


// all elements where key==1
$KeysWithOne = array_filter($query, 'KeyIsEqualToOne');

// all elements where key==0
$KeysWithZero = array_filter($query, 'KeyIsEqualToZero');
```

**Otherwise** you could always keep a state variable to see when the switch was made:

```
$HasSeenZeroValue = false;
foreach ($query as $sample){
  // ...
  if ($sample['key'] == 0 && !$HasSeenZeroValue){
    echo '<tr><td>...</td></tr>';
    $HasSeenZeroValue = true;
  }
}
```

*Though, admittedly, I don't 100% get what you're asking.*

Comment: Apparently my [ESP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrasensory_perception) is operational. ;-) Glad to help!